# Error when decoding image

Tags: c#, asp.net, barcode-scanner

I am trying to use MessagingToolkit to decode an image in C#/ASP.NET. I have managed to encode a qr using this package, but when i try to decode, using the code below it comes up with 2 errors (at the bottom of the page)

I believe this is because I am not getting the image correctly after uploading, but can someone point out exactly where I have gone wrong. Thanks.

```
    protected void CreateCode_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string path = "C:\\Users\\Wayneio\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\BAMSystem\\BAMSystem\\";
        if (QRUpload.HasFiles == true)
        {
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(QRUpload.FileName);
            string extA = fi.Extension;
            if (extA == ".jpg" || extA == ".png")
            {
               QRCodeDecoder decoder = new QRCodeDecoder();
               QRUpload.SaveAs(path + QRUpload.FileName);

               System.Drawing.Image myImg = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(path + QRUpload.FileName);
               decoder.Decode(myImg);

            }
            else
            {
                error.Text = "You have uploaded a " + extA + " file. Please upload either a PNG or a JPG";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            error.Text = "You have not uploaded an image.";
        }
    }
```

Error1:

```
Error   2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Drawing.Image' to 'MessagingToolkit.QRCode.Codec.Data.QRCodeImage'  c:\users\wayneio\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\BAMSystem\BAMSystem\default.aspx.cs  38  35  BAMSystem
```

Error2:

```
Error   1   The best overloaded method match for 'MessagingToolkit.QRCode.Codec.QRCodeDecoder.Decode(MessagingToolkit.QRCode.Codec.Data.QRCodeImage)' has some invalid arguments    c:\users\wayneio\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\BAMSystem\BAMSystem\default.aspx.cs  38  20  BAMSystem
```

P.S if anyone has documentation on this MessagingToolkit QR package, it would be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decode  accepts 'Bitmap' type image.

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap myImg = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(FileName);
Dictionary<DecodeOptions, object> decodingOptions = new Dictionary<DecodeOptions, object>();
List<BarcodeFormat> possibleFormats = new List<BarcodeFormat>(10);

                        possibleFormats.Add(BarcodeFormat.DataMatrix);
                        possibleFormats.Add(BarcodeFormat.QRCode);
                        possibleFormats.Add(BarcodeFormat.PDF417);
                        possibleFormats.Add(BarcodeFormat.Aztec);
                        possibleFormats.Add(BarcodeFormat.UPCE);
                        possibleFormats.Add(BarcodeFormat.UPCA);
                        possibleFormats.Add(BarcodeFormat.Code128);
                        possibleFormats.Add(BarcodeFormat.Code39);
                        possibleFormats.Add(BarcodeFormat.ITF14);
                        possibleFormats.Add(BarcodeFormat.EAN8);
                        possibleFormats.Add(BarcodeFormat.EAN13);
                        possibleFormats.Add(BarcodeFormat.RSS14);
                        possibleFormats.Add(BarcodeFormat.RSSExpanded);
                        possibleFormats.Add(BarcodeFormat.Codabar);
                        possibleFormats.Add(BarcodeFormat.MaxiCode);

 decodingOptions.Add(DecodeOptions.TryHarder, true);
 decodingOptions.Add(DecodeOptions.PossibleFormats, possibleFormats);
Result decodedResult = decoder.Decode(myImg, decodingOptions);

          if (decodedResult != null)
                        {
                          //.. success
                        }
```

Also you can also omit the "decodingOptions" options parameter as decoder also has an overload Decode(Bitmap image).

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap myImg = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(FileName);
Result decodedResult = decoder.Decode(myImg);

          if (decodedResult != null)
                        {
                          //.. success
                        }
```

If you want only QRCode decoding,

```
    System.Drawing.Bitmap myImg = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(FileName);
    Dictionary<DecodeOptions, object> decodingOptions = new Dictionary<DecodeOptions, object>();
    List<BarcodeFormat> possibleFormats = new List<BarcodeFormat>();
    possibleFormats.Add(BarcodeFormat.QRCode);                              
    decodingOptions.Add(DecodeOptions.TryHarder, true);
    decodingOptions.Add(DecodeOptions.PossibleFormats, possibleFormats);
    Result decodedResult = decoder.Decode(myImg, decodingOptions);
     if (decodedResult != null)
       {
          //.. success
       }
```

You can find documentation and code here
http://platform.twit88.com/projects/show/mt-barcode

Sample code ..download here ..has demo code also
http://platform.twit88.com/projects/mt-barcode/files

Code project here
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20574/Open-Source-QRCode-Library

Comment: Thanks, so this should also work, instead of a list?          

decoder.Decode(myImg, BarcodeFormat.QRCode);

Comment: no..it will need the list.. in your case a list with one element.you can remove the entries which are not needed. But its good to have those entries/formats as it will makes the decoding logic more resilient if the Bar code format changes. Also you can also omit the "decodingOptions" options parameter as decoder also has an overload Decode(Bitmap image). I will update the answer too.